# Throw exception in ActionResult method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-services, exception, soap

I have a view with a upload controller wich fires this ActionResult:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ProcessSubmitUpload(HttpPostedFileBase attachments, Guid? idDocument)
    {
          //Validations
          var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(attachments.InputStream);
          DocumentCommonHelper.SendFile(xmlDocument);
    }
```

The SendFile method:

```
  public static void SendCte(XDocument xmlDocument)
  {
       var client = new WsSoapClient();
       client.InsertXML(xmlDocument);
  }
```

The webservice returns SoapException if somethig goes wrong, like: 
"The IDDocument does not exist" , etc etc.

But in MVC when im debugging if something goes wrong in the InsertXml method i cannot catch it, the debug navigation just stop and throw a Upload File error.

I would like to catch the return message of the InsertXML method in my action e return it to my view. Like a 'alert' popup.
How can i do that?

Comment: use `try{}catch{}` to catch the error. If you want a pop-up I would look into using a [Jquery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) . Working with the action async through jquery or javascript will allow you to catch the message or HTML returned and generate your dialog box.

Comment: @James what kind of exception i need to handle?

Comment: you should handle whatever exceptions you think could be returned first, then always handle `exception` last to catch any others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return the error message to the view in the ModelState object. The view can display it using a ValidationSummary helper:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessSubmitUpload(HttpPostedFileBase attachments, Guid? idDocument)
{
      //Validations
      var xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(attachments.InputStream);
      try
      {
          DocumentCommonHelper.SendFile(xmlDocument);
      }
      catch(Exception ex)
      {
          ModelState.AddModelError("ProcessSubmitUpload", ex.Message);
          return View(new MyViewModel())
      }
}
```

View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("ProcessSubmitUpload", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    ... etc.
}
```

Comment: The ex.Message property of the Exception type will return the InsertXML response? Can i use 'throw new ' in this case?

Comment: It will contain the description of the exception thrown in your SendFile (or InsertXML) method.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your second question. If you throw a new exception in the handler here, you will get the yellow screen of death (or your own custom error page if configured). If you want to give the user a message, you need to handle the exception (as in my example) and return a user error message to the view for display in a way that is compatible with other error messages (eg. validation). ModelState is the normal way of doing that, as that is what MVC uses for validation messages.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your `SendFile` method call with `try..catch` block and it `catch` section fill return result with appropriate information about fault.